# Server-Client push notification with Python

Tags: python, push-notification

I'm building an client application, which connect to a server and wait for signal from server to do something (think about chat app).
For example: user 1 has client 1 and 2, user 2 has client 3, the server would send the message to the channel "user 1" and only client 1 and 2 will have the message.

I know about Websocket and Long-polling, but can't find a server which is self-hosted and easy to test. Initially I want to make a proof-of-concept first before dive in later.

Nginx push stream seems to fit my need, I can create a channel, and notify all client connect to that channel, seem good enough to use, but I can't find any Python client implement

AutoBahn and some other Python server seem only create one channel and broadcast.

Can someone give me a correct direction.

Comment: Autobahn includes a full-featured WAMP (http://wamp.ws) implementation capable of doing PubSub over arbitrary numbers of channels.

Comment: Sadly Autobahn only available in Python, Ruby and Java, which isn't a widely adopted protocol (WAMP)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

have a look on Python tornado http://www.tornadoweb.org/.

It is in fact a non-blocking webserver and you have a WebSocketHandler object which might be very useful for what you want to do.

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html

Regards

Comment: Ended up deciding with Tornado (specially the Socket.IO with Tornado) or Nginx Push Stream

Comment: Excellent choice. =) Tornado + socket.io its a brilliant combination for WebSocket programming.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org/) which implements a push-pull client server interface.

Comment: seems good, but what I need is a channel, for example: user 1 has client 1 and 2, user 2 has client 3, the server would send the message to the channel "user 1" and only client 1 and 2 will have the message.  From what I read ZeroMQ doesn't fit it, right ?

Comment: I think it does. Have a look at the pipelie pattern: http://api.zeromq.org/2-2:zmq-socket